# is NSDictionary non-ordered completely

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

As we know,NSDictionary is non-ordered.however,when keys is number,when the dictionary is printed,they are printed by ascending number. i have try many times.

Comment: The output of `description` for any object other than a NSString and a few others is arbitrary and can change from release to release.  It is not to be relied on.

Answer (score 1):

the order of a dictionary depends on the value that is returned by the hash method of the added key-object. it is very like, that NSNumber returns its value, it is was created with an Integer. in that case your observation would be correct.

more infos: http://bynomial.com/blog/?p=73

try ing this code

```
NSArray *numbers = @[@0,@1,@2,@3];
for (NSNumber *n in numbers) {
    NSLog(@"%ld:%@", (unsigned long)[n hash], n);
}
```

it produces this output

```
0:0
2654435761:1
5308871522:2
7963307283:3
```

seems as if Knuth's hash algorithm was implemented half.

The original is

```
hash(i)=i*2654435761 mod 2^32
```

here it seems to be just

```
hash(i)=i*2654435761
```